# Multiple grandients and radial gradient in background

Tags: html, css, gradient

This is what i want to achieve
[image: This is what i want to achieve]

Is it possible to get a similar result with CSS gradients? I'm was playing with radiant but I couldn't create something similar. (Here are some of my tries).

```
background-image: radial-gradient( circle at top right, #016CB4, black 20%, transparent 40% ), radial-gradient( circle at bottom left, #016CB4, BLACK 20%, transparent 40% );
```

and

```
background: radial-gradient(circle, #016CB4, black),radial-gradient(circle, #016CB4, black),radial-gradient(circle, white, #016CB4),radial-gradient(circle, #016CB4, black);
```

Comment: Better use this image and use background-repeat: repeat.

Comment: Can you add screenshots or viewable snippets of your attempts? Also your example looks very random, which makes reproducing it difficult. How much do you want the result to look like the example? You'll probably need dozens of layers in the end to get something similar.

Comment: Remember, we are coders, who code, and the languages are not graphic designing software, just use any image designer, to create image effects, put back the resulting image in html, **I recommend not to waste your time** on using a coding language to create graphics. Moreover, others won't mostly answer this and waste their time! There is aldeready an answer posted,take a look at it or if it is not what you need, do as I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you should use coordinates instead of, for example `top right`

It would look like this `radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, #2296e5, transparent 30%)`
The first 0% is the horizontal position and the second one the vertical. So 0% 0% is the top left and 100% 100% would be bottom right.

Then it's just a matter of randomizing the values and adding enough gradients till you're satisfied.

I would recommend using an [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) loop for that.

Here is what that looks like

```
@function noise($color) {
  $val: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, $color, transparent 30%);
  @for $i from 1 through 50 {
    $color2: darken($color, $i*0.9);
    $val: #{$val}, radial-gradient(circle at random(100) + #{'%'} random(100) + #{'%'}, #{$color2}, transparent 30%);
  }
  @return $val;
}

@mixin addnoise($color) {
  background: noise($color);
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  @include addnoise(#2296e5);
}
```

Which compiles to:

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, #2296e5, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 19% 51%, #1e94e5, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 59% 93%, #1b92e3, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 56% 94%, #1a8fdf, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 26% 90%, #1a8ddb, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 6% 65%, #198ad7, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 5% 100%, #1987d3, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 93% 21%, #1885cf, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 6% 68%, #1882ca, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 97% 33%, #177fc6, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 43% 53%, #177dc2, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 30% 60%, #167abe, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 68% 43%, #1678ba, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 5% 49%, #1575b6, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 99% 21%, #1572b2, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 92% 60%, #1470ae, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 85% 30%, #146daa, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 91% 6%, #136aa5, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 37% 9%, #1368a1, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 48% 66%, #13659d, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 82% 62%, #126299, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 15% 80%, #126095, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 20% 92%, #115d91, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 49% 79%, #115b8d, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 81% 70%, #105889, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 16% 63%, #105585, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 32% 28%, #0f5381, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 8% 6%, #0f507c, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 77% 39%, #0e4d78, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 81% 20%, #0e4b74, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 87% 40%, #0d4870, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 18% 76%, #0d456c, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 61% 45%, #0c4368, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 20% 22%, #0c4064, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 39% 52%, #0b3d60, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 44% 37%, #0b3b5c, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 3% 59%, #0a3857, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 58% 20%, #0a3653, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 64% 37%, #09334f, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 55% 12%, #09304b, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 52% 36%, #082e47, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 3% 75%, #082b43, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 92% 94%, #07283f, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 37% 96%, #07263b, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 66% 92%, #062337, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 43% 2%, #062033, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 69% 81%, #051e2e, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 51% 68%, #051b2a, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 99% 15%, #041926, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 17% 85%, #041622, transparent 30%), radial-gradient(circle at 72% 69%, #04131e, transparent 30%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```